# SproutCore Programmatically fire item selection in MenuPane

Tags: javascript, view, dom-events, sproutcore

We are using SproutCore v1.6 and trying to programmatically set the selected menu item. The `MenuPane` looks like the following.

```
OurPage = SC.Page.design({
    myAccountMenu: SC.MenuPane.create({
        layout: { width: 200 },
    
        items: [
          { title: 'Sign Out', action: 'signOut' }
        ],
    
        itemActionKey: 'action',
        itemTitleKey: 'title'
    })
});
```

We are then trying to set the 'selectedItem' as follows.

```
OurPage.getPath('myAccountMenu').set('selectedItem', OurPage.getPath('myAccountMenu').items[0])
```

This sets the selected item correctly and we can query the following to get the item:

```
OurPage.getPath('myAccountMenu').get('selectedItem')
```

However it never actually triggers the actions on the menu. e.g. It doesn't actually sign the user out. However when you manually click the menu item it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A few things

1)  Use an outlet on your page to get the accountMenu

```
OurPage = SC.Page.design({
    menu: SC.outlet('myAccountMenu'),

    myAccountMenu: SC.MenuPane.create({...})
});
```

that way if the path to `myAccountMenu` changes, you only have to change your outlet.

2)  To set the item, just do

```
var toSelect = OurPage.getPath('menu').items[0];
OurPage.setPath('menu.selectedItem', toSelect);
```

3)  Looking at the code, there is no easy way to invoke the action when programmatically setting the selection.  Thats because the items you pass in get turned into `MenuItemView` instances, and those fire their actions on `mouseUp`.

However, if you are using statecharts (or even if not), you can just grab the action off the item and invoke it

`App.statechart.sendEvent(toSelect.action);`